# Configuring Spring Security for Oauth and Http Basic authentication

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, spring-security

Within my Spring-Boot app using spring-security, I would like have some REST calls (API) to be authenticated via http basic authentication only, but all other requests should be handled via OAUTH2 (standard Oauth2 webapp with redirection to an authorization endpoint).

Http basic authentication is activated using http.httpBasic(), 
and oauth is activated using the @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation. But with the following configuration also my API calls are redirected to the authorization endpoint, which is not what I am aiming for. Any ideas?

```
@EnableOauth2Sso
@Configuraiton
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the section of the docs I should be looking at: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

Answer (score 0):

You can use authorizeRequests().antMatchers() and classify the resources based on the URI patterns for OAuth based or Http Basic Security.